# Cannot update UI from other task in win forms?

Tags: vb.net

I have four complex tasks running parallel, I want to update a rich textbox with the log file.
The approximate program structure is as follows:

```
Sub buttonClick ()
   complextask1 'code goes here
   complextask2 'code goes here
   complextask3 'code goes here
   complextask4 'code goes here
end sub
```

The above four tasks updates a log file, which I have to display in a `RichTextbox` control.
I tried with an infinite `while` loop, and updating the `textbox`, but my `UI` is getting hanged.

Comment: Can you post up your code?

Comment: how about callback method?

Answer (score 0):

You must run heavy task in separate thread or background worker
First read and study about threading here is a sample coding for you task
Import these to your form class

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Create a local variable in your form

```
Private syncContext As SynchronizationContext
```

Create method for your task

```
Private sub DoTask()
   complextask1 'code goes here
   complextask2 'code goes here
   complextask3 'code goes here
   complextask4 'code goes here
End Sub
```

On button click create new thread and execute heavy task

```
Sub buttonClick ()
    syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext()
    Dim newThread As Thread
    newThread = New Thread(AddressOf DoTask)
    newThread.Start()
End Sub
```

To update your UI status create one method for it

```
Private sub UpdateStatus(byval State As Object)
    Dim myText As String = CType(State, String)
End Sub
```

Now to call UI method use following statement in your DoTask Method

```
Dim NewStatus As String = “This Is New Status”
syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), NewStatus)
```

complete code will look like this

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Private syncContext As SynchronizationContext
    Private Sub buttonClick ()
        syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext()
        Dim newThread As Thread
        newThread = New Thread(AddressOf DoTask)
        newThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private sub DoTask()
        Dim NewStatus As String
        complextask1 'code goes here
        NewStatus=”New Task Done”
        syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), NewStatus)
        complextask2 'code goes here
        NewStatus=”New Task Done”
        syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), NewStatus)
        complextask3 'code goes here
        NewStatus=”New Task Done”
        syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), NewStatus)
        complextask4 'code goes here
        NewStatus=”New Task Done”
        syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), NewStatus)
    End Sub

    Private sub UpdateStatus(byval State As Object)
        Dim myText As String = CType(State, String)
    End Sub
End Class
```